# Pthread - time of execution

Tags: c++, multithreading

Why the variable `a` doesn't assume the values 0 or -1 but 0 and 1?

```
pthread_mutex_t stop = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int a = 1;

void* decrement(void* arg)
{ 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&stop);
    if(a > 0) { a--; } 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&stop);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid, tid1;
    pthread_attr_t tattr;
    pthread_attr_init(&tattr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&tattr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    pthread_create(&tid, &tattr, decrement, NULL);
    pthread_detach(tid);
    pthread_create(&tid1, &tattr, decrement, NULL);
    pthread_detach(tid1);   
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why are you detaching the threads? (Twice each, for emphasis?)

Comment: Your read of `a` in the last line of `main` is unprotected, which is a bug.

Comment: to run its in parallel

Comment: It runs in parallel either way, you just removed any chance of waiting for completion.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the line:

```
if(a > 0) { a--; }
```

a could not be equal to -1 if it isn't decremented when it is equal or less than 0...